# How to disable link when hold click html

Tags: javascript

I'm making an image track so when I click down to drag the track I got jump into the href so I cannot drag the track while I'm holding down to the image and only the outside of the track

```
document.getElementById("image-2").onclick = function () {
  location.href = "section-2.html";
};

document.getElementById("image-3").onclick = function () {
  location.href = "section-3.html";
};

document.getElementById("image-4").onclick = function () {
  location.href = "section-4.html";
};

document.getElementById("image-5").onclick = function () {
  location.href = "section-5.html";
};

function disableLongPress(element) {
  var mouseDownTime;
  var mouseUpTime;
  var timeDifference;
  element.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    mouseDownTime = new Date().getTime();
  });
  element.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
    mouseUpTime = new Date().getTime();
    timeDifference = mouseUpTime - mouseDownTime;
    if (timeDifference > 1500) {
      event.PreventDefault(onclick);
    }
  });
}
```

I'm expecting to disable the href when hold click but it is still able to click when click once

Comment: `onclick` should only occur if you actually click, so `mousedown` - `mouseup` so this sounds a little weird but with no example I cannot really see what is going wrong. You could try to add a drag event-listener: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/drag_event or update the question with a little more context and maybe even a working example so we can see what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

By registering separate handlers for `click` and `drag` actions you can define different actions for each of them.

You have two separate events:

- [drag event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/drag_event) - executed when the element is dragged
- [click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) - executed on mouse click (down and up)

```js
const img = document.getElementById('test');

test.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('click');
  // Perform your onClick action
})

test.addEventListener('drag', () => {
  console.log('drag');
  // Perform your onDrag action
})
```

```html
<img id="test" src="https://placehold.co/400">
```

If this implementation is not what you want you can probably look into using:

- [mouse down event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event)
- [mouse up event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseup_event)

And measuring the time difference between mouse down (click) and mouse up (release). Then based on your time threshold have a different action e.g.

- If events are within 100ms - perform click actions
- If events are more than 100ms apart - perform hold actions